# Как обратиться к глобальной переменной внутри функции

Tags: php

Не могу обратиться к глобальной переменной $pdo через global, в чем может быть проблема?

```
<?php 
    $user = "****";
    $password = "*****";
    $host = "****";
    $db = "******";
    $pdo = new PDO("mysql:host=$host;dbname=$db", $user, $password);

function handler(){
    $about_title=$_POST["title"];
    $about_description=$_POST["description"];
    
    if($about_title or $about_description != null){
        $row="UPDATE about SET title=:title,description=:description";
        $query = global$pdo->prepare($row); #тут ошибка
        $query->execute(["title"=>$about_title, "description"=>$about_description]);
        echo '<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0; URL=/admin/settings_about.php">';
    }
}
    ?>
```

Comment: В PHP есть глобальный массив $GLOBALS https://www.php.net/manual/ru/reserved.variables.globals.php

Comment: Рекомендую к ознакомлению, в вашем случае возможное решение
https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1416163/Как-правильно-организовать-логику-подключения-к-базе-обучающий-пример/1416878#1416878

Comment: Вообще глобальные переменные - это общепризнанное зло, но если сильно надо, то перед первым использованием переменной в функции написать `global $varname;`, тогда в функции будет доступ к глобальной `$varname`

Comment: да я так и сделал через global, но почему то не видит..

Comment: @1znaetvse Вы сделали не так) `function handler(){ global $pdo; $about_title=$_POST["title"]; .... }`

Comment: или `$query = $GLOBALS['pdo']->prepare` если уж хотите

Answer (score 0):

Проблема решена через глобальный массив $GLOBALS